# Can't access elements of an eigen linear system solution

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm just started of using eigen but for some strange reason I'm struggling with something that should be simple. The code below is a simplified version of some similar computation I would like to perform (Solve x in Ax = b).

Input:

```
auto N = 10;
auto A = Matrix<Float, Dynamic, Dynamic>::Identity(N, N);
auto b = Matrix<Float, Dynamic, 1>::Constant(N, 1, 1);
std::cout << "A: " << std::endl
          << A << std::endl
          << "b: " << std::endl 
          << b << std::endl;
auto x = A.fullPivLu().solve(b);
std::cout << "x(" << x.rows() << ", " << x.cols()
          << "): " << std::endl << x << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
A: 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
b: 
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
x(10, 1): 
mouse: /home/jansen/devel/build/external/eigen/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Block.h:119: Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false>::Block(XprType &, Index) [XprType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, BlockRows = 1, BlockCols = -1, InnerPanel = false]: Assertion `(i>=0) && ( ((BlockRows==1) && (BlockCols==XprType::ColsAtCompileTime) && i<xpr.rows()) ||((BlockRows==XprType::RowsAtCompileTime) && (BlockCols==1) && i<xpr.cols()))' failed.
[1]    21192 abort (core dumped)  ./src/mouse
```

A and b is well formed and the solution x even have the right dimensions but whenever I try to access an element of x I get an assertion failure. From the assertion I deduce that some sort of out of bounds error happens but I can't figure out why?

Comment: What element are you trying to access?  Are you using the right basis for indexing (looks like they're zero based indexes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't abuse of `auto` with expression template libraries, see this [page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicPitfalls.html#title1). Typically, in your case, `x` is not a `Matrix<>` object but an abstract object saying that `A\b` as to be computed... The solution is thus:

```
Matrix<Float, Dynamic, 1> x = A.fullPivLu().solve(b);
```